# Network error when creating a project in react

Tags: reactjs, vite

a few hours ago I activated several network functions to be able to share documents from one PC to another that are connected on the same network, but since I did that it no longer lets me create projects with create-react-app or create vite. I already reset the network options to their factory state and still it keeps giving me the same error. The error is this:

```
npm create vite
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/create-vite failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:123:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-04T22_51_20_596Z-debug-0.log
```

Thanks in advance

As I mentioned before, I tried to restore the network to its factory state on the computer as well as reinstall nodejs and nothing worked

Comment: If you are in an entreprise network it might be that you have to configure your npm registry. Ask around about the url of the npm registry and then configure it with : npm config set registry (your registry url)

Comment: I'm not in a business environment

Comment: npm ping is the command to test the connectivity to the registry. It has to return a PONG with a response time 1 s or less

Comment: When doing npm ping I get the same error

Comment: have you tested your internet connectivity for instance with ping 8.8.8.8

Comment: yes, it does send the normal ping

Comment: It can be that you are in a region of the world where npm servers are overloaded at the moment. That is if it usually works well.

Comment: ok, if I connect to another network if it works for me, what can I do in that case?

Comment: Sorry but I do not have any solution.

Answer (score 0):

To create a project with vite use

```
npm create vite@latest
```

You can checkout vite [official doc](https://vitejs.dev/)